# What is the difference between "little" and "a little" (as adverbials)?

Tags: difference

What is the difference between "little" and "a little" (when used as adverbials)? Is it the same as between "few" (not enough to matter) and "a few" (enough to matter, but not a lot)? Say

> I slept **little** *[meaning "cut me some slack"]*

> I slept **a little** *[meaning "I may not have had the best sleep of my life, but generally I'm in the game"]*

Are my guesses correct?

No! It's not a duplicate! I looked at some other questions that concerned "little". The answers didn't address this specific question

Comment: Yes, you are correct in your assumption.

Comment: Few people would actually say: sleep little would usually come in a longer sentence, especially in writing. Usually, one would say: I didn't get much sleep. So comparing them is moot.

Answer (score 1):

From my perspective (as an American native speaker) the first example has an old-fashioned and sarcastic feel. It could be rephrased (still old-fashioned, only adding an implied word) "I slept but little." Meaning I didn't get much sleep.

"I slept a little" is modern usage. It can be more optimistic. It could mean "I didn't get much sleep, but I slept a little." But it could still be delivered sarcastically to mean that the speaker did NOT get enough sleep.

A way to emphasize that in written form would be "I slept... a little." Or "I slept. A little."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right. *Little*, and *few* are [negative polarity items](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item), *a little* and *a few* are not.